# Ajax result dependant on PHP result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP function that gives an response for an alert if the result is `> 0` however I am getting an empty alert if the result is `0`

How can I stop this?

```
 function urlCheck()
{
    $website_id = $this->input->post('website_id');
    $post_title            = $this->input->post('post_title');

    $urlCheck = $this->page_model->pageURLCheck($post_title,  $moviesparx_website_id);

    if($urlCheck > 0)
    {
        echo "This page name already exists";
    }
}
```

**jQuery Ajax:**

```
 $.ajax({
            url:url,
            data:data ,

            type: 'POST',
            success: function (resp) {
                alert(resp);
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: success is deprecated use .done () instead... also console.log (resp) to see what you are getting back. Another thing.. is the alert supposed to print "this page name already exists?" if so you need to convert this to json and apply headers to it correctly.

Comment: That is because you are sending the response only if result > 0

Comment: @xlordt Why does he need to convert it to JSON? With no conversion, `resp` will simply be the text that the PHP echoes.

Comment: @xlordt Can you provide me an example

Comment: @Barmar making sure, this is why I asked him what it was, it wasnt to clear to me if his end result was going to be just that text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are sending the response only if result > 0.Send another response if your result is <= 0.So write an else case like the following.

```
 function urlCheck()
{
    $website_id = $this->input->post('website_id');
    $post_title            = $this->input->post('post_title');

    $urlCheck = $this->page_model->pageURLCheck($post_title,  $moviesparx_website_id);

    if($urlCheck > 0)
    {
        echo 1;
    }
    else{
       echo 0;
    }
}
```

Ajax

```
 $.ajax({
            url:url,
            data:data ,

            type: 'POST',
            success: function (resp) {
                if(resp){
                  alert('This page name already exists');
                }
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't want the else I want it to do nothing no alert

Comment: @Jess McKenzie Try my answer, but your question was very hard to understand tbh

Comment: Well if you dont want to show the alert based on the response recived

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
$.ajax({
            url:url,
            data:data ,

            type: 'POST',
            success: function (resp) {
        if(resp == '')
            //do something
        else
            alert(resp);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do another check in the client side:

Server

```
<?php

if ($urlCheck > 0) {
   echo '1 - This page name already exists.';
} else {
   echo '0 - New page name.';
}
?>
```

Client:

```
// success handler
success: function(resp) {
   var realResp = resp.split('-');
   if (realResp[0] == '1') {
      alert(realResp[1]);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't want the else I want it to do nothing no alert

Comment: @Jess McKenzie That's why I added a status code in front of the message and do a client side check to alert only when the status check is 1, indicating $urlCheck > 0

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
if($urlCheck > 0) {
    echo "This page name already exists";
} else {
    echo -1;
}
```

Client -

```
success: function (resp) {
    if(resp != -1) {    
        alert(resp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a fully working example.. NOTE: since you are using a class I had to improvise with something

```
<?php

  function urlCheck ($urlCheck)
  {
      if ($urlCheck > 0) echo "This page name already exists"; exit;
  } 

  if (isSet ($_POST ['send']))
  {
       urlCheck (1);
  }
?>


 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>blah</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready (function (){
         $.ajax({
                url: "index.php",
                data: {send: "data"},
                type: 'POST',
            }).fail (function () {
                console.log ("failed");
            }).done (function (data){ //dont use success
                alert (data);
            });
     });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Here is why I state not to use success:

> Deprecation Notice
>
> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callback
>   methods introduced in jQuery 1.5 are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To
>   prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(),
>   jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.